# Why doesn't recursive_dict from the lxml FAQs work?

Tags: python, lxml

In the [lxml FAQs](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts), they provide the following:

> **How can I map an XML tree into a dict of dicts?**
>
> I'm glad you asked:

```
def recursive_dict(element):
     return element.tag, \
            dict(map(recursive_dict, element)) or element.text
```

But when I try to use this, I get the following:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS')
>>> xml_dict = recursive_dict(lxml.etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(r.content)))

AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Is there a step I'm missing to convert the ElementTree into elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lxml.etree.parse` returns an `ElementTree` object, NOT an `Element` object. From the [documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class):

> An ElementTree is mainly a document wrapper around a tree with a root
>   node. It provides a couple of methods for serialisation and general
>   document handling.

`ElementTree.getroot()` returns the root element of the document:

```
xml_doc = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
xml_dict = recursive_dict(xml_doc.getroot())
```

**EDIT**

Here is a variation of `recursive_dict` that is probably better suited:

```
def recursive_dict(element):
    retval = {}
    retval["tag"] = element.tag
    if element.text:
        retval["text"] = element.text

    if element.tail:
        retval["tail"] = element.tail

    if element.attrib:
        retval["attributes"] = element.attrib

    if len(element) > 0:
        retval["children"] = [recursive_dict(child_element) for child_element in element]

    return retval
```

Comment: Hm, that stops the `AttributeError`, but the resulting dict is rather anemic compared to the XML doc itself.

Comment: recursive_dict is pretty limited. For instance: a) No attribute values b) If an element has two (or more) children with same tag name, only one child will end up in the dict. A better recursive_dict() can easily be created that has children as a list and attributes as a separate dict for each node.

Comment: Yeah, bizarre that it's in the FAQs in such a terrible format. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would anyone happen to know a way to create an actual etree document using this dictionary format as input?

Answer (score 1):

I do realise that I'm roughly 7.5 years late on this, but the suboptimal implementation still sits in the FAQ unchanged and I wanted to share my solution here because it's a prominent search result when looking for answers concerning this and someone might eventually find it useful.

For my use case, I wanted a version between what is in the FAQ and what codeape provided. This version allows access to child nodes just by their tags, but if there's more than one child node with the same tag, there will be a list of dictionaries, not just the dictionary for the last value. Should also be adaptable fairly easily if you need more bells and whistles.

This is what I ended up using:

```py
def recursive_dict(element):
    """Takes an lxml element and returns a corresponding nested python dictionary.
       If there's multiple child elements with same tag, it will have a list of them.
       Improvement on https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts"""
    
    # Trivial case returns only the element text.
    if len(element) == 0:
        return element.text
    
    # Nested case returns a proper dictionary.
    else:
        retval = {}
        
        for child in element:
            # Recursive call computed, but not placed yet.
            recurse = recursive_dict(child)
            
            # No previous entry means it's now a single entry.
            if child.tag not in (retval):
                retval[child.tag] = recurse
                
            # Previous single entry means it's now a list.
            elif type(retval[child.tag]) is not list:
                oldval = retval[child.tag]
                retval[child.tag] = [oldval, recurse]
                
            # Previous list entry means the list gets appended.
            else:
                oldlist = retval[child.tag]
                retval[child.tag] = oldlist + [recurse]
                
        return retval
```